# cdbreact module from react bootstrap throwing export error

Tags: reactjs

am using React Bootstrap 5 Footer component form cdbreact which i found in this link https://www.devwares.com/docs/contrast/react/components/footer/  i have done eveyrthing as per the doucment but its showing me an error "***export 'CDBFooter' (imported as 'CDBFooter') was not found in 'cdbreact'***"

```
here is my code 

import React from 'react';

import { CDBFooter, CDBFooterLink, CDBBtn, CDBIcon, CDBContainer } from 'cdbreact';

 const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <CDBFooter className="shadow">
      <CDBBox
        display="flex"
        justifyContent="between"
        alignItems="center"
        className="mx-auto py-4 flex-wrap"
        style={{ width: '80%' }}
      >
        <CDBBox display="flex" alignItems="center">
          <a href="/" className="d-flex align-items-center p-0 text-dark">
            <span className="ml-4 h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold">Devwares</span>
          </a>
          <small className="ml-2">&copy; Devwares, 2022. All rights reserved.</small>
        </CDBBox>
        <CDBBox display="flex">
          <CDBBtn flat color="dark" className="p-2">
            <CDBIcon fab icon="facebook-f" />
          </CDBBtn>
          <CDBBtn flat color="dark" className="mx-3 p-2">
            <CDBIcon fab icon="twitter" />
          </CDBBtn>
          <CDBBtn flat color="dark" className="p-2">
            <CDBIcon fab icon="instagram" />
          </CDBBtn>
        </CDBBox>
      </CDBBox>
    </CDBFooter>
  );
};


export default Footer





and there is the message error 


ERROR in ./src/components/Footer/Footer.js 9:30-39

export 'CDBFooter' (imported as 'CDBFooter') was not found in 'cdbreact' (possible exports: CDBAccordion etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing a

```
yarn upgrade
```

resolved this error for me. I had been using other CDB components so I figure the footer must only be available in newer versions. This was my first use of it in my project